# MySql create a link between 1 or 2 tables

Tags: mysql, database, diagram

[image]

Does there is a cleaner way to do this ?

The Products table is linked to the sub_categories table, but if there is no sub_categories for a category, I make a link between the Products table and table categories ?

Comment: A category can have 0 to many sub categories so I would think that your relationship would be from categories to sub categories. I am not a MySql Ninja by any means but that seems like the correct path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this.  Depending on the depth level of categories and also what your preferred implementation can implement using either of the following approaches.

**Adjacency List model**
A single categories table with a self referencing parent_id column that is populated for each sub category.

**Nested Set model**
A single categories table with "lft" and "rgt" columns to denote the position within the set. "lft" and "rgt" mean Left and Right respectively as "LEFT" and "RIGHT" are reserved words in SQL.

There is a fantastic full blog post with examples and diagrams explaining in great detail how both these approaches work - [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

I would also recommend looking at libraries, in your chosen language, that may take some of the work out what you want to achieve.